# Couchbase Query in C# gives empty objects when called with fixed type class

Tags: c#, .net, couchbase

Couchbase Server 4.0
OS: Windows 7
Client SDK: CouchbaseNetClient.2.2.5
Visual Studio 2013, C# 4.5

```
var query_res1 = m_bucket.Query<MyClass>("select * from MyData limit 10");
var query_res2 = m_bucket.Query<dynamic>("select * from MyData limit 10");
```

query_res1 gives me a list of typed data, but the objects are empty (elements are default(T)) (so as created with new, but not de-serialized)

query_res2 works "correct": the list of dynamic objects contains my data from the bucket.

the data class:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyClass
{
    [JsonProperty("dateTime")]
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public double Value { get; set; }

}
```

Thanks for any Idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the query to:

```
"select MyData.* from MyData limit 10"
```

The reason is that the SDK expects the query results to be returned as an array of the document values, but what it gets from the n1ql query service is an array of document values wrapped in another object as a property under the bucket name. Selecting MyData.* removes the extra object wrapper and returns the document values directly.

Answer (score 0):

query_res1 gives me a list of typed data, but the objects are empty (elements are default(T)) (so as created with new, but not de-serialized)

You have two situation

1.
==> I think the object are empty because this field you created in your "MyClass" is not same as data from query, such as

DateTime  # daytime
Value # value

should the data from query and properties have the same?

2. I think you shouldn't create a field name same with dataType

   [JsonProperty("dateTime")]
   public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }